# How to store data grid into datatable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I need to store datagridview selected rows into datatable in single columns like below

DataGridView

```
user1 user2 user3
ram   sam   ravi
```

DataTable

```
values
ram
sam
ravi
```

I tried below code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("values",typeof(string));

foreach (DataGridViewRow gridRow in dataGridView_settings.Rows)
{
      DataRow dtRow = dt.NewRow();

      for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_settings.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
          dtRow[0] = gridRow.Cells[i].Value;
          dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
      }
}
```

Problem is its adding only one row in the datatable then showing error "This row already belongs to this table."

Comment: error cleared by placing DataRow dtRow = dt.NewRow(); inside for loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store select row in datagrid into datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328131/how-to-store-select-row-in-datagrid-into-datatable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the DataRow creation to the inner for

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("values",typeof(string));
foreach (DataGridViewRow gridRow in dataGridView_settings.Rows)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_settings.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
          DataRow dtRow = dt.NewRow();
          dtRow[0] = gridRow.Cells[i].Value;
          dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
      }
}
```

Comment: its inserting all rows into datatable.how to do only selected row

Comment: If you want to add only selected rows, change the outer foreach, changing Rows by SelectedRows:
foreach (DataGridViewRow gridRow in dataGridView_settings.SelectedRows)